# jstree validate renaming of node, and if not validated , roll back to old name

Tags: javascript, validation, contextmenu, rename, jstree

while renaming a node in jstree, I wanted to validate for special characters in renaming, and if found , I wanted to alert user, and roll back to the old name.

for that I have added

- rename context menu
- after that I did bind with node_rename and rename event
- in binding I check for event.type === node_rename
- I am able to validate special characters of new name as I get new name in data.args[1]
- but before my alert comes, rename is already taken place, and I dont find a way to undo that.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of binding `rename_node`, I needed to bind to `rename.jstree`, and then needed to use rollback of action.

Here the bind event code.

```
if(type === 'rename')
{
        var new_Name = data.rslt.new_name;
        var iChars = "!@#$%^&*()+=[]\\\';,/{}.-_|\":<>?";
        for (var i = 0; i < new_Name.length; i++) 
        {
            if (iChars.indexOf(new_Name.charAt(i)) != -1) 
            {
                alert ("Special characters are not allowed.");
                $.jstree.rollback(data.rlbk);
            }
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it through `rename_node`. If validation fails call:

```
$('#yourtreeid').jstree("refresh");
```